# Wifi Stops responding

Tags: networking, wifi

**Summary**

Wifi connects to my access point fine. It will run for anywhere from a couple seconds to a few minutes before it stops responding. It says it's still connected to the network, but DNS lookups seem to fail - browser says *connecting* before eventually failing with an "unable to find" error. It will then "come back" after waiting for a minute or so and the DNS lookup will succeed and whatever I was trying to load will load. But the Wifi will stop responding again after a minute or so with the same symptoms. ***But*** if I have Nordvpn running everything is fine - wifi never goes out and the internet works as expected.

**System**

Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 5

```
                                       sdean@x1c5
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMmds+.        OS: Linuxmint 5 elsie
 MMm----::-://////////////oymNMd+`     Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.10.0-20-amd64
 MMd      /++                -sNMd:    Uptime: 1h 9m
 MMNso/`  dMM    `.::-. .-::.` .hMN:   Packages: 2277
 ddddMMh  dMM   :hNMNMNhNMNMNh: `NMm   Shell: zsh 5.8
     NMm  dMM  .NMN/-+MMM+-/NMN` dMM   Resolution: 1600x900
     NMm  dMM  -MMm  `MMM   dMM. dMM   DE: GNOME
     NMm  dMM  -MMm  `MMM   dMM. dMM   WM: Muffin
     NMm  dMM  .mmd  `mmm   yMM. dMM   WM Theme: Mint-Y-Dark-Pink (Mint-Y)
     NMm  dMM`  ..`   ...   ydm. dMM   GTK Theme: Mint-Y-Aqua [GTK2/3]
     hMM- +MMd/-------...-:sdds  dMM   Icon Theme: Mint-Y-Aqua
     -NMm- :hNMNNNmdddddddddy/`  dMM   Font: Ubuntu 10
      -dMNs-``-::::-------.``    dMM   Disk: 58G / 241G (26%)
       `/dMNmy+/:-------------:/yMMM   CPU: Intel Core i7-7600U @ 4x 3.9GHz [49.0°C]
          ./ydNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM   GPU: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
             \.MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM     RAM: 3153MiB / 15760MiB
```

*Note: I was running it on Linux Mint 21.0 and had the same issues*

Some other potentially useful info:

```
$ route -n                              
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.86.1    0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlp4s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp4s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-68d430a47d2f
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-0bafb649454b
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-65553a0d1569
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e110d1251ad2
192.168.86.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0
```

```
$ ifconfig
wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.86.30  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.86.255
        inet6 fd8f:a209:b552:0:6aec:c5ff:fe0a:f221  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::6aec:c5ff:fe0a:f221  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 68:ec:c5:0a:f2:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 19344  bytes 13531781 (12.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13074  bytes 3081937 (2.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Things Tried (and failed)**

- Explicitly setting the gateway to `192.168.86.1` via `route add`
- Turning off wifi power management using `sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 power off`
- Turning off IPv6
- Changing/Re-installing OS
- Probably a few other things that I can't remember

Anything you can suggest to help me solve this problem. I don't mind running my VPN all the time, but it screws up connecting to things on the internal network, so I need things to work without it.

Please let me know if I've missed anything and any information that might help pinpoint the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Two devices on my network - the laptop and a Raspberry Pi - were using the same IP. The Pi has a static IP set and the laptop uses a dynamically assigned IP. I'm not sure why the router was assigning an already in use IP to the laptop, but that's what was happening. I had to go into the router config and reserve the static IP for the Pi then a new IP was assigned to the laptop. Problem solved.

Comment: If the router was not told that the static IP was already assigned the it could not know not not assign the IP to another system. Best bet would be to tell DHCP to assign the IP to a know MAC address.

Comment: @doneal24 that's exactly what I ended up doing. Surely an oversight on my part in the first place.